# How to arrive at a specific formulation of the relative median deviation? Related to integration and statistics.

Tags: calculus, probability, integration, statistics, probability-distributions

So my title is not very specific but here is the question in more detail.
I am an economist currently working with this book: [Frank Cowell - Measuring Inequality](http://darp.lse.ac.uk/papersdb/Cowell_Measuringinequality3.pdf)

On page 25 a formulation of the relative mean deviation is given as follows:
$$
M = 2 \left[ F\left(\bar{y}\right) - \Phi(\bar{y}) \right]
$$

$F$ is the CDF, $\Phi$ is the proportion of total income received by persons who have an income less than or equal to $y$ ( per the book's definition: $\Phi=\frac{1}{\bar{y}} \int_0^y zdF(z)$), and $\bar{y}$ is the mean. 
All this is also defined on page 152 in the appendix. 
The appendix also gives a definition of $M$:

$$
M = \int \left| \frac{y}{\bar{y}} -1\right|dF
$$

The book says that the former formulation can be derived from the latter, but I have no idea how to begin with this. How do I perform the integration here and get to the first formulation?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Also why does it say median in your title but the question is about mean?

Comment: I think ive done it. I will post a solution soon.

Comment: The methodological problem here is that the first relation contains definite integrals while the second is given as an indefinite integral. What are the (effective) integration limits for the second relation? Since $y$ is income, are they $(0,\infty)$?

Comment: Yes they are $(0, \infty)$

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I think you want your variable to be positive, so replace all the $-\infty$ in my proof by 0.

[image]

Comment: (+1) for the _literally_ back-of-the envelope calculation -which is also correct. The crucial thing here is that the way $M$ is defined, its value is decomposed symmetrically around $\bar y$, irrespective of whether $F$ is a symmetric distribution or not.

Comment: @AlecosPapadopoulos thanks and oh nice answer to the random walk identity. If did asks something, it was never going to be easy, so kudos to you.

Comment: Thanks. But these are the really enjoyable ones.

Comment: @option_select replace all the $-\infty$ by 0. It does not matter what the lower limit of your random variable is. It can be -10, 7/2 or $e^\pi$. I used $-\infty$ because a general random variable is defined on $(-\infty,\infty)$ and certainly that is how the integral in your text book should be interpreted, because he did not write down the domain of integration

Comment: Ok, then I think that you have got it.

Comment: Just one final thing that is probably fairly noobish, but for the integration it is irrelevant whether the variable y is in the integral but also contained in $F(y)$. Is that generally the case?

Comment: @option_select please say say that again, I don't quite follow.

Comment: If we assume $F$ is differentiable (which is, for standard distributions, then $dF(y) = f(y) dy$ where $f$ is the pdf of the distribution. Maybe you are more use to this notation? $y$ is the 'dummy' variable being integrated over so the $y$ bit inside the integral is the thing being integrated over.

Comment: Yes, I am more used to the other notation, but both result in the mean. I think I follow.